# MVC4 Force session update before request ends

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

We are developing using VS2010 and MVC4, deploying our web app on an IIS 7.5 on Windows7.

Our project has a long running process for which we want to display status and progress.

In order to accomplish this we have a small serializable class with properties that describe the current status. The long operation pseudo code goes like this:

```
int curentPercentComplete = 0;
EngineStatus status = new EngineStatus();
while (!done) {
    status.PercentComplete = curentPercentComplete;
    Session['status'] = status;
    // do lengthy operation
    curentPercentComplete = compute();
    done = isJobFinished();
}
```

We also have an other controller action that tries to retrieve the current status from the session
which then encodes to json and returns it to the browser via an Ajax request.

Our problem is that we always seem to get the last saved data from the previous request, in other words the session object does not seem to update the Session['status'] field during the execution of the while block.

We have tried the session state mode both InProc and StateServer with exactly the same behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the lengthy process a async? that updates the done flag? while it is running at different stages?  If you want to debug it will please use a string and keep appending the currentPercentComplete value to it. So that you can find how exactly the session value got updated at different stages.

Comment: @GirishSakhare All code inside the while loop runs synchronously. To be honest the actual implementation runs using a for lopp that iterates a specific number of times.

Comment: In that case you will only get 2 states i.e. 0 % and 100%. try string status = status + " " + currentPercentComplete; Session["Status"] = status; to see exact execution behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the MVC framework performs a single update of the session data at the end of the request which means that only the last value is saved.

Since the "lengthy" operation is performed in a single request-response cycle, the idea of storing intermediate status information in the session is plain wrong.